# wildcard subdomain with mod_wsgi + apache + pyramid

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I've created a wildcard subdomain using cpanel and attempting to point all sub domains to a particular .wsgi file.

```
<VirtualHost my.server_ip.address:9999>
    ServerName _wildcard_.domain.tld
    ServerAlias *.domain.tld
    # DocumentRoot /home/my_acct/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.tld
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/_wildcard_.domain.tld combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/_wildcard_.domain.tld-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."

    ## User my_acct # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled my_acct
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup my_acct my_acct
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup my_acct my_acct
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid my_acct my_acct
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
        #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
        AssignUserID my_acct my_acct
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/my_acct/public_html/cgi-bin/
    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/my_acct/wildcard_safe.domain.tld/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
```

The following code is what is in **wildcard_safe.domain.tld/*.conf** and there is only 1 .conf which I name it as subdomain.conf

```
SetEnvIf Host "^(\w+).domain.tld" subdomain=$1

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid_subdomain user=my_acct group=my_acct threads=4 \
python-path=/home/my_acct/modwsgi/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/my_acct/modwsgi/env/pyramidsub_%{ENV:subdomain}.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /admin /home/my_acct/modwsgi/env/pyramidsub_%{ENV:subdomain}.wsgi

<Directory /home/my_acct/modwsgi/env>
    WSGIProcessGroup pyramid_subdomain
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The following is the **pyramidsub_test.wsgi** file

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ini_path = '/home/my_acct/modwsgi/env/MyFirstApp/production_subtest.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

I've also ensured that there's a pyramidsub_test.wsgi in /home/my_acct/modwsgi/env/.

After setting all this up, I did a apache restart, and go to test.mydomain.com.
However it is showing a website not found, I've checked on apache error_log, but I can't
find any errors being logged. However, I have no problem viewing the main 
domain ( www.domain.com )

This is my first time doing server setup, etc, coming from a php background.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the difference between `pyramidsub_www.wsgi` and `pyramidsub_test.wsgi`?